# preconditioner for block conjugate gradient in matlab

Tags: matlab

I'd like to solve a system of linear equations, AX = B, where A is relatively big sparse and positive definite JxJ matrix. B is a matrix rather than a column vector with dimension JxS.

One way to go is to "tweak" this problem so that the standard pcg routine would work, for instance:

```
design=kron(speye(S),A)
X=pcg(design,B(:));
```

However, the above is not possible for me because the matrix `design` is simply too big to be stored, even after exploiting its sparsity. A better solution is therefore to run pcg without storing the matrix `design`, that is

```
afun=@(x)  reshape(A*reshape(x,J,[]),[],1);
X=pcg(afun,B(:));
X=reshape(X,J,S);
```

Now I get to my question: is there a way to allow for a preconditioner (e.g. from `ichol`) to the  the code written above *without* storing any additional matrix?

I am saying this because `X=pcg(afun,B(:));` takes forever to converge, hopefully a preconditioner could help in this case.

Answer (score 0):

While you should know that `pcg` does already use a preconditioner, either you give it explicitly or not, if you really really want to use the `ichol` conditioner, there is no better option than the one that is explicitly described with [an example in the documentation...](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pcg.html)

> Use ichol with only one input argument to construct an incomplete
>    Cholesky factorization with zero fill.
>
> `L = ichol(A);`
>
> `[x1,fl1,rr1,it1,rv1] = pcg(A,b,1e-8,100,L,L');`

As per your matrix called `design`, its nowhere to be seen in your code, so I guess that solves the need of storing it.

Comment: Hi Ander, thanks for your reply. I probably wasn't clear enough. My question is whether I can pass for a block diagonal pcg framework like the one described initially a preconditioner without storing any matrix L. I've modified my original post so that hopefully now it is clear...

Comment: @kb87 If there is another matrix in the system, you MUST store it. However, you could call the function as `pcg(A,b,1e-8,100,ichol(A),ichol(A)')` , but it will be stored internally.